# Error displaying Arabic characters from entity in visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

When I use visual studio 2013 to display Arabic characters they are displayed properly but when I use visual studio 2015 the arabic characters are displayed with strange characters (ÇáãÌãæÚÉ) if I use entity classes , but if I use a model the Arabic characters are displayed properly. What is wrong with entity in visual studio 2015?

```
namespace SimpleIAP
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class tblProduct
{
    public tblProduct()
    {
        this.tblPurchaseDetails = new HashSet<tblPurchaseDetail>();
        this.tblProductOpeningBalances = new HashSet<tblProductOpeningBalance>();
        this.tblSalesInvoiceDetails = new HashSet<tblSalesInvoiceDetail>();
        this.tblStores = new HashSet<tblStore>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DisplayName("رقم المنتج")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "مطلوب")]
    [DisplayName("اسم المنتج")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "مطلوب")]
    [DisplayName("المجموعة")]
    [ForeignKey("tblCategory")]
    public int CategoryID_FK { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("الوصف")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("حد إعادة الطلب")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "أرقام فقط")]
    public int ReOrderLimit { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("سعر القطاعى")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)", ErrorMessage = "أرقام فقط")]
    public decimal PriceRetail { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("سعر الجملة")]
    [RegularExpression(@"(^\d*\.?\d*[0-9]+\d*$)|(^[0-9]+\d*\.\d*$)", ErrorMessage = "أرقام فقط")]
    public decimal PriceWholeSale { get; set; }

    public virtual tblCategory tblCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblStore> tblStores { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblPurchaseDetail> tblPurchaseDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblSalesInvoiceDetail> tblSalesInvoiceDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tblProductOpeningBalance> tblProductOpeningBalances { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Har4.png)

Comment: Which one is not displaying properly ? The one in your data annotation attributes or something else you stored in the db ?

Comment: The issue is not an mvc or asp.net issue. check this fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/aZ78IK) is it only in VS or also when you run your code?

Comment: thanks for reply , the one in the data annotation in code first classes in my entity is giving problem.the problem occures when running code but in visual studio all looks good , but in vs2013 the code looks good in both vs and when running code